# Add old NSDictionary value to a newer NSDictionary within 2 for loops

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

So I have a bit of a dilemna I'm trying to solve; I'm trying to 'merge' two NSArrays of NSDictionaries. One array is the fresh, aka valid friends list one, and the older array is any previously chosen recipients when you're picking/composing. All I'm trying to do is copy one object from the old NSDictionary into the new one, if that friend still exists in our new NSArray of NSDictionaries.

Basically, if you tap a table cell in the recipients picker, I save that for the Selected state key of the NSDictionary. So, when the next time I check to see if you're still friends with those before, I want to save this Selected state, as I refresh the table view and display any new friends you're with. I pre-set the Selected state to `[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]` when I get the fresh valid friends list every 60 seconds, so that's why I'm wanting to merge the prior Selected state when you're picking recipients.

I've tried nesting the for loop, but the previous Selected object never gets set. I take it the object never gets set because the inner for loop doesn't return before the outer for loop, but I'm not sure how to go about this correctly. I truly appreciate any help! Thank you. Here is my method:

```
- (void)updateOurRecipientsWithArray:(NSArray *)newFriendsArray
{   
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in newFriendsArray)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:dict];

        for (NSDictionary *sub in appDelegate.composeFriendsArray)
        {
            // This below line checks to make sure they're still a valid friend
            if ([[newFriendsArray valueForKey:@"username"]containsObject:[sub objectForKey:@"username"]])
            {   // This below value never gets set correctly
                [newDict setObject:[sub objectForKey:@"Selected"] forKey:@"Selected"];
            }
        }

        [newArray addObject:newDict];
    }

    appDelegate.composeFriendsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[appDelegate sortedArray:newArray]];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UpdatePriorRecipients" object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your if condition by below way:

```
if ([[newDict valueForKey:@"username"] isEqualToString:[sub objectForKey:@"username"]])
```